# Overlay analysis in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial

I have two spatial tables in Oracle.

Table A contains line or point features and has columns:

```
ID
GEOM
SERIAL NUMBER OF MAP LIST
```

Table B contains polygons of MAP LIST:

```
ID
SERIAL NUMBER OF MAP LIST
```

I need to produce spatial analysis where features from table A take a serial number of map list from table B on basement of result of spatial analysis.

For example, line feature is in polygon ABC213, so I have to fill `SERIAL NUMBER OF MAP LIST` attribute by `SERIAL NUMBER OF MAP LIST` attribute value from table B.

How can I do that?

Comment: What are the map lists and where are their serial numbers coming from? There doesn't appear to be anything to link the data in the two tables, except the serial number you're trying to find. Is there some other table or look-up mechanism you haven't mentioned? Some sample data and expected results would also be helpful.

Comment: Map list is a polygon feature in TABLE B. And I need to proceed spatial analysis, probably INTERSECT... If feature from TABLE A is in area of some feature from TABLE B, I need to set attribute SERIAL_NUMBER_OF_MAP_LIST of feature from TABLE A in accordance with INTERSECT with feature from TABLE B.

Answer (score 0):

it would look something like this in Oracle spatial (i'm using 12C)

```
select * from
tableA a, tableB b
where sdo_relate(a.geomColumn,b.geomColumn,'mask=anyinteract')='TRUE';
```

There are different types of masks, take a look here
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/GUID-97C17C18-F05E-49B4-BE11-E89B972E2A02.htm#SPATL1039